# Django no module named elasticsearch_dsl.connections

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, python-import, importerror

I'm trying to connect my Django model to the Elasticsearch server on local host but when I try

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections
```

I get the error "ImportError: No module named elasticsearch_dsl.connections".
When I use this same command in the Django shell, it works fine.

search.py

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections
from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Text, Date, Boolean, Integer, Keyword, fields
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

from .models import HomeGym, Country, Rating

connections.create_connection()

class HomeGymIndex(DocType):
    title = Text()
    price = fields.FloatField()
    tags = Keyword()

    city = Text()
    country = Text()

    rate = Integer()
    opusApproved = Boolean()

def bulk_indexing():
    HomeGymIndex.init()
    es = Elasticsearch()
    bulk(client=es, actions=(b.indexing() for b in HomeGym.objects.all().iterator()))
```

This leads to an ImportError on line 1. "No module named elasticsearch_dsl.connections"
The same import statement works in the shell though.

I've already done a pip install of elasticsearch and elasticsearch-dsl inside my virtualenv.

Here is the file structure

```
my_website/
    elasticsearch/
        #elasticsearch files pulled from github
        elasticsearch-5.5.2-SNAPSHOT/
            #elasticsearch files
            bin/
                elasticsearch
    opus/
        manage.py
        homegymlistings/
            models.py
            search.py
            #other standard app files
        opus/
            #standard files for main django branch
    my_virtualenv/
        bin/
            activate
```

Why does my import statement only fail when called inside the search.py file located inside the homegymlistings app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I had to pip install elasticsearch and elasticsearch-dsl *outside* of the virtualenv. The error went away after that.

Answer (score 4):

Run this

`pip install elasticsearch_dsl`